# Eliminé un Servlet y todavía la encuentro al llamarlo | Creé un Servlet y no existe al llamarlo

Tags: java, eclipse, servlets, clase, eclipse-oxygen

En mi proyecto en JAVA WEB, eliminé un Servlet y todavía puedo tener acceso a ella, (incluso cuando creo un servlet con el mismo nombre me dice que ya existe el servlet con dicho nombre) además creé un Servlet para poder utilizarlo y no tengo acceso al llamarlo, (como si nunca la hubiese creado).

Que puede ocasionar estos problemas?

cómo puedo solucionarlo??

Estoy utilizando Eclipse Oxygen

Answer (score 0):

Al utilizar una plataforma como Java debes seguir un ciclo de edición->compilación->ejecución, tratandose de Servlets es normalmente que se requiera un paso de deployment(instalación) antes de la ejecución. Eclipse Oxygen es un IDE que solo te sirve para los dos primeros pasos y opcionalmente puede aplicar el deployment. Después de hacer tus cambios (edición), deberas generar un archivo .war (compilación), ese archivo lo utilizarás para hacer el deployment en tu servidor de aplicaciones que es un software aparte de Eclipse puede ser por ejemplo: Tomcat, Jetty.
Una vez completado el paso de deployment podrás ejecutarlo y observar tus cambios